# MySQL text index only checks 256 chars?

Tags: mysql, indexing

MySQL's UNI key on a text column seems to only look at the first 255 characters to test for uniqueness. If I have two strings that begin with the same 255 characters they cannot both be added to this table.

Is there a way to overcome this?

The reason why I keyed this field is to ensure uniqueness regardless of query (those aren't under my control), rather than for performance.

Comment: what type of your UNI key ? If varchar, how many length do you set ?

Comment: I thought you can't create an index on fields > 255 chars.

Comment: Can you show us the `CREATE TABLE` statement

Comment: The create table showed a limit of 255 characters. I think this was the default when it was created (not by me). The limit on indices seems to be 1000bytes, which is 333 characters in the default UTF-8 encoding. I changed the encoding to ASCII (I was saving C++ function names) which could be indexed up to 1k characters.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `function_name` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`(1000))
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1000004 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not index text fields in MySQL with key length more than [255 symbols before MySQL 4.1.2](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/column-indexes.html) / [1000 bytes (767 for InnoDB) for higher versions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-indexes.html) - and you can not overcome that natively.

The easiest solution is to evaluate md5 hash and store it in another column, then create unique index by it and create a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html) `before insert` & `before update` which will insert md5 automatically for you. If you're running MySQL server 4.x - then you'll need to handle that by yourself (since no trigger will be available)

Comment: I accepted this answer since it made sense, but it wasn't what I did in the end.

Comment: Actually the limit is 1000 bytes and the number of characters this translates to is dependent on encoding. When I'm using the default of UTF-8, the limit is 333 characters.